# Как заполнить ListView который находится в HubSection?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windowsphone

Создал я Hub примерно такой:

```
<Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Margin="0,76,0,0">
    <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Карта" FontSize="20">
       <DataTemplate>
           <my:MapControl />
       </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection x:Name="hb2" x:Uid="HubSection2" Header="Местоположения">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="gridm">
                <ComboBox >
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Последняя" IsSelected="True"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="За последние сутки"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="За неделю"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <ListView x:Name="list"
                          Foreground="White" Margin="5,58,5,5" 
                          ItemClick="list_ItemClick" 
                          SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" 
                          Header="123456123" RequestedTheme="Light" 
                          SizeChanged="list_SizeChanged">
                </ListView>
            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate>
     </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Так вот до ListView не могу достучаться C#, постоянно пишет что list не доступен в данном контексте...
Как достучаться до list в моем случае?

[image: Пример]

Comment: В каком файле вы хотите достучаться? В вашем случае должен быть *.xaml.cs

Comment: @S.Kos Именно! Кусой кода разметки приведен из файла Page1.xaml. А скриншот из Page1.xaml.cs.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `x:Name="list"`  на `Name="list`

Comment: @S.Kos не помогло, он дальше HubSection name не видит... то есть gridm не видит и тд(

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь MVVM, извините за вопрос?

Comment: @VladD Я только начал осваивать программирование под wp, и мне как то не все понятно пока, было бы хорошо если бы кто то подсказал как нужно... Действительно эту задачу у меня получилось решить с помощью MVVM, но после я наткнулся на новую проблему, у меня не получается обновлять данные после изменений... После изменения DataContext, данные на странице не меняются(

Comment: @VladD Ну вот и эту проблему удалось решить=) А люди задают тупые вопросы не по тому что тупые, а потому что тупят. Вот я например знаю что по хорошему нужно MVVM использовать в данной задаче, но в одной мелочи я затупил и застрял на этом, для понимания решил действовать в лоб, но там тоже забуксовал, и вот тут как и в жизни было бы не плохо если бы кто то вытащил, те сказал бы элементарную вещь, ту самую что я упустил из виду по тому что зациклился на неверном пути решении...

Comment: По поводу вашей проблемы: приведите больше кода. Кто знает, может вы пытаетесь достучаться из статической функции. // По поводу обновления с MVVM, может быть, вы забыли реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged у вашей VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private ListView getListFromElement(Hub hub)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < hub.Children.Count; i++)
     {
          if (hub.Children[i] is ListView) 
          {
              ListView list = (ListView)hub.Children[i];
              return list;
          }
      }
      return null;
 }
```

Вызываете так:

```
 ListView list = (ListView)getListFromElement(Hub);
```

Comment: Странно hub.Children пишет что метод недопустим в данном контексте...

Comment: я в документации вообще не нашел метод Children у hub.

Comment: думаю что так как задается DataTemplate у HubSelection, то невозможно получить доступ из code-behind

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, жаль, буду искать варианты дальше... Пофиг уже на ListView, я его смог заполнить уже иначе, а вот что я до MapControl не могу добраться, вот это плохо(

Comment: разобрался=) Можно присвоить событие контролу loaded например, создать экземпляр, нужного контрола, когда событие происходить в экземпляр записывается объект который сработал. Например   private MapControl myMapControl; private  void myMapControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myMapControl = (sender as MapControl);}

Comment: Хорошо, но лучше все же смотреть в сторону MVVM)